# Is there a good translation for "Dark horse"?

Tags: translation, phrase-request

Ich habe gerade versucht, den englischen Ausdruck "Dark horse" zu übersetzen, und es hat gar nicht funktioniert :). Obwohl das immer witzig ist, kann jemand mir helfen mit einer Übersetzung?

Comment: ist ein "Dark Horse" gleichzusetzen mit einem "Hidden Champion"? Den Begriff hab ich hierzulande nämlich ab und an schon gehört.

Comment: @lady Ein "Dark horse" ist einer (meine Meinung nach) dass sehr stark und kompetetiv ist, und normaleweise "erreicht" etwas, aber vorher nicht bekannt ist.  @lady Ein "Dark horse" ist einer (meine Meinung nach) dass sehr stark und kompetetiv ist, und normaleweise "erreicht" etwas, aber vorher nicht bekannt ist.  Also Deine einschätzung klingt ziemlich gut.

Comment: ah, hab grad nochmal nachgeschaut. "Hidden Champion" hat nur eine sehr eingeschränkte Bedeutung: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Champions - außerdem heißt es nicht dasselbe, weil ein Hidden Champion noch immer unbekannt ist, wenn er schon "Champion" ist. :)

Comment: @lady Schade.  Trotzdem, danke schon.

Comment: Könntest Du ein paar typische Verwendungen nennen und den Versuch einer Umschreibung geben? Ansonsten sage ich, dass das ein dunkles Pferd ist.

Comment: @GlenWheeler Bei Fragen nach einem passenden Äquivalent zu einem idiomatischen Ausdruck bitte immer gleich in der Frage umschreiben, was in der Ausgangssprache damit gemeint ist. Gerade, wenn dieser Ausdruck eher umgangssprachlich ist, dürfte er Muttersprachlern der *Ziel*sprache eher nicht vertraut sein.

Comment: Es ist schon viele Jahre als ich an diesen Frage gedanken habe! Hier gibt eine Erklaerung der Meingungs von "Dark Horse" (aber ich glaube schon dass viele es schon kriege):

"a little known, unexpectedly successful entrant. someone who was previously unknown, but suddenly emerges into prominence. someone who keeps their skills and ideas secret and surprises others by doing something unexpected. a person who wins a race or competition though no one expected them to win."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Dict.cc bietet folgende Übersetzungsmöglichkeiten:

- unbekanntes Rennpferd
- (erfolgreicher) Außenseiter
- stilles Wasser (von *stille Wasser sind tief*, also jemand, dem man mögliche Fähigkeiten oder Eigenschaften nicht ansieht)
- unbekannte Größe (d. h. nicht einzuschätzen)
- unbeschriebenes Blatt (d. h. keine bekannte Erfahrung oder Erfolge, möglicherweise aber mit Potenzial)

Die Erklärungen sind von mir.

Comment: +1 for *unbeschriebenes Blatt*

Comment: Ach ja, unbeschriebenes Blatt scheint auch sehr nutzbar, ich werde versuchen es in meinem Kopf zu erhalten.

Comment: Nach der Bedeutungserklärung auf [thefreedictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dark+horse) ist "unbeschriebenes Blatt" sicherlich keine gute Übersetzung dafür. "unbekanntes Rennpferd" habe ich noch nie gehört. "stilles Wasser" kommt dem schon bedeutend näher (oder erfolgreicher Aussenseiter, aber das "erfolgreich" muss aus dem Zusammenhang ersichtlich werden, nicht explizit angegeben. @Glen Wheeler: behalten, nicht erhalten ;)

Comment: @phant0m: Gemessen an den angebotenen Übersetzungsmöglichkeiten würde ich wagen wollen zu behaupten, dass es keine hundertprozentige Übersetzung gibt. Daher muss man halt erheblich mehr Kontext mitbringen, um eine Übersetzung vorzunehmen. "Stilles Wasser" passt in meinen Augen im Pferderennsport nicht unbedingt, aber in anderen Zusammenhängen ist es vielleicht nicht schlecht. "Unbekanntes Rennpferd" wird von dict.cc aber auch nicht als bildliche Übersetzung angeboten (im Gegensatzu zu den anderen Möglichkeiten). "Das Pferd ist ein unbeschriebenes Blatt" finde ich jetzt aber auch nicht absurd.

Comment: Ja, ich denke auch, dass es keine richtige Übersetzung gibt. So wie ich das verstand, ist der "Rennpferd"-Kontext mehr als ein Beispiel zu verstehen, nicht dass "dark horse" meistens so gebraucht wird. Du hast natürlich recht, je nach Zusammenhang macht das eine mehr oder weniger Sinn.

Answer (score 8):

Ich hätte noch **Geheimtipp** und **Geheimfavorit** vorzuschlagen, auch wenn hier meist *vor* dem "Rennen/Wettbewerb/…" darüber spekuliert wird, ob es sich um einen Gewinner handeln könnte.

Eventuell **entpuppt** sich diese Antwort ja als **Überflieger** und stellt die bisherigen Antworten in den Schatten. ;-)

(Wenn ich es richtig verstehe, könnte dann diese Antwort als Dark Horse bezeichnet werden, oder?)

Answer (score 5):

Wenn ich "Dark Horse" richtig verstehe, dann handelt es sich um einen Mitspieler o.ä., der ganz vorne dabei ist, den aber keiner der Beobachter kennt und/oder einschätzen kann.

Hierfür gibt es im Deutschen den Ausdruck **Außenseiter**, der eine ähnliche Konnotation mitbringen *kann*, aber nicht muss.

Comment: Bedeutet Außsenseiter nicht "outsider", also eine das wahrscheinlich nicht erfolgreich ist?  Vielleicht deswegen sagst Du "kann".

Comment: @Glen: es kann tatsächlich beides bedeuten, und es kommt sehr auf den Kontext an. OregonGhost [schrieb](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1490/is-there-a-good-translation-for-dark-horse/1494#1494) deshalb "erfolgreicher Außenseiter", das macht es eindeutiger. Ich hatte das Wort allerdings positiver in Erinnerung als es die [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Au%C3%9Fenseiter#Sport) beschreibt. Demnach ist ein "Außenseiter" tatsächlich nur der "outsider" oder "underdog".

Comment: Danke.  Es sieht so aus, dass es viele Möglichtkeiten gibt :).  (Aside: Du hast bestimmt "Dark horse" richtig verstanden!)

Answer (score 4):

"Dark horse" kann zwei Bedeutungen haben:

- unbeschriebenes Blatt

Und wie wohl eher bezüglich deines Falles

- eine unbekannte Größe

Geheimer Champion, Geheimtipp... kommt dem allem sehr nahe.
Geheimtipp finde ich persönlich am besten.

Jemand, der über sich selbst oder Aktivitäten wenig offenbart bzw jemand, der über unerwartete Talente oder Möglichkeiten verfügt.

Die Frage wurde zwar schon vor längerer Zeit gestellt, aber vielleicht hilft sie jemandem, der in Zukunft danach sucht.

Answer (score 3):

Ein dark horse ist nicht wirklich ein Außenseiter. das Dark Horse ist der Spieler, das Pferd, das keiner auf dem Zettel hat. Es ist "die Unbekannte" in der Gleichung.

Das kann daran liegen, dass das Dark horse noch nie aufgetreten ist, oder aus niedrigen Ligen kommt, wo kein Rampenlicht auf es, ihn, sie gefallen ist.

Eigentlich metaphorisch recht gut im Ausdruck abgebildet, kommt das "dark horse" aus dem Dunklen, wo kein Licht hinfällt, wo es also niemand gesehen hat oder sehen konnte.

Also eher der / die unbekannte Größe. Erfolgreich muss das dark horse dabei nicht sein. Man kennt es nicht. Es kann genauso gut ein Rohrkreppierer wie auch ein Champion werden. Newbie ist hiermit nicht zu verwechseln, da das der Neuling an sich ist. Da ist die Formulierung dark horse dann doch noch schwammiger, weil man es gar nicht einschätzen kann.

Vorschläge: Die unbekannte Größe, die Unbekannte, Der Faktor "X". (ganz entfernt: Graue Eminenz, ist aber schon zu qualitativ hochwertig)

Comment: *grau* impliziert Alter. *dunkel* wird in der Tat mit der Bedeutung *unbekannt* verwendet, vgl *Verdunklungsgefahr*, *Dunkelziffer*, *Herkunft dunkel*. Dabei ist *dunkel* wohl ursprünglich eher als *fremd* zu deuten, möchte ich meinen, ohne die Assoziation zur Nacht in Abrede zu stellen.

Answer (score 1):

Man könnte es auch umschreiben:

> 1 - jemanden nicht auf der Rechnung (gehabt) haben

Also z.B. "Diesen Läufer hatte vorher niemand auf der Rechnung."

Es stellt sich allerdings immer erst nachträglich heraus, dass jemand ein *dark horse* war.

So ähnlich:

> 2 - jemanden nicht auf seinem Radar (gehabt) haben

Von da ist es nicht weit bis zu

> 3 - unter jemandes Radar fliegen / sich unter jemandes Radar bewegen

So spricht man z.B. von Start-Ups oder Investments, die unversehens groß herauskommen könnten. Beispiel: "Die Fondsberater halten europaweit Ausschau nach attraktiven Aktien, die unter dem Radar der meisten Anleger sind."

Da könnte man dann auch Ausschau halten nach

> 4 - Blümchen, die im Verborgenen blühen

Ähnlich wie 1 bis 3 wäre

> 5 - etwas nicht auf dem Schirm (gehabt) haben

Das benutze ich jedoch eher für 'an etwas nicht gedacht' bzw. 'etwas übersehen haben', das ich eigentlich hätte im Blick haben müssen.

Es gibt sicherlich etliche weitere Möglichkeiten.